# "Duplicate Value for resource" Error after adding play-services-nearby Library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My relevant gradle configuration looks like this

```
final SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = '23.1.1'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:17.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
```

Everything was working until i added play-services-nearby:17.0.0 library. After adding that library I get this error when running the project:

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\fd6c1de212e0cc84b448609e27a51207\design-23.2.0\res\values\values.xml:19:5-827: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''.
```

Is there anything I can do to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using very old version. If you want to use **`play-services-nearby:17.0.0`** then libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:

- Upgrade compileSdkVersion to 28 or later.
- Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX).

AndroidX replaces the original support library APIs with packages in the androidx namespace. Read official guideline about [**`AndroidX Overview`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx).

```
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
```

Your dependencies will

```
 implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
 implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
 implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
 implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
 implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:17.0.0"
```

Note - You can use implementation **`"com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:16.0.0"`** for Temporary solutions. For Permanent solutions you should move to Androidx.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using play-services-nearby:16.0.0 and it worked. Anyway thank You to IntelliJ's answer.